# nltk tree.draw cannot plot the Syntax Tree of Chinese

Tags: canvas, tkinter, nlp, nltk, tkinter-canvas

```
from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
import logging

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost', port=9000, 
                      lang='zh',
                     logging_level=logging.DEBUG)
from nltk.tree import Tree

sentence ='今天天气很好，一起去散步吧'
parser = nlp.parse(sentence)
parser
tree = Tree.fromstring(parser)
# tree.pretty_print()
tree
tree.draw()
```

This is my code.
I have tried many ways.
I know tree.draw() is based on tkinter.
I can draw English, but cannot draw Chinese.

[image]

help me.
in this picture, Chinese Characters are gone.

The right form is like this
[image]

Comment: can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you saying that the Chinese Characters are not drawing?

Comment: yes, Chinese Characters has gone